# Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist have tried most solutions

Tags: react-native

I have pretty much tried all the solutions but none of them seem to work.

```
An error was encountered processing the command   (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain,   code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier     build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app/Info.plis
```

Print: Entry,   ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

How do you get the project to run?

Comment: This is a very poor error message that react-native run-ios sometimes gives, because PListBuddy tries to read a config file that was supposed to be created by a previous build step, that failed.

Have you tried running the app from XCode? You might get a more informative error message.

Comment: Will try that tomorrow. Thanks for the reply jevakallio.

Comment: Seems to be working in Xcode.  I think it might be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My terminal pops out the same message due to deleting some simulators I don't use in Xcode.

If you run `react-native run-ios` with no specific parameters, react-native will run the default simulator which is iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.1 in my case and I deleted this simulator by chance.

Here comes my error messages:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { id:F3A7BF54-B827-4517-A30D-8B3241C8EBF8 }

Available destinations for the "albums" scheme:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CD64F26B-045A-4E27-B05A-5255924095FB, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7 inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8FC41950-9E60-4264-B8B6-20E62FAB3BD0, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:991C8B5F-49E2-4BB7-BBB6-2F5D1776F8D2, OS:10.3.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9 inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B9A80D04-E43F-43E3-9CA5-21137F7C673D, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:58F6514E-185B-4B12-9336-B8A1D4E901F8, OS:10.3.1, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
```

. . .

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myapp.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

In order to get rid of these, open up your Xcode and check for available simulators (as same as terminal listed) and run `react-native run-ios --simulator="your device name"`

For my case, I run `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 7"`, the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was opening the project in xcode and run the project there. Xcode then had a few problems for me. The first problem was that I had the wrong device selected to be used for testing.

[image]

I made sure that iPhone X simulator was selected (for some reason it was defaulting to my ipad which wasn't setup to be a dev device).

Then make sure when you run you have no red warnings. I had one more red warning and that was because I didn't select the project's team profile.

[image]

I also changed the bundle identifier to my company name to be unique.

Running it in xcode is the best way to know what the error is. Don't rely on react-native alone to figure out your errors.

Answer (score -1):

it works for me when I deleted `~/.rncash`

---

react-native info

```
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.1
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4258U CPU @ 2.40GHz
      Memory: 78.15 MB / 8.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 8.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.3.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338
      Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728 => 16.6.0-alpha.8af6728
      react-native: 0.57.4 => 0.57.4
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```